# Missing template arguments before '.' token

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I am trying to organize my program into functions and have ran into this,

> error: "missing template arguments before '.' token"

once I try to run the code in the function, it works fine if its just in `main()`. Anyone familiar with this error know what the issue may be?

Note, the commented out code removes the error but messes with the ordered list `class` and resets its length or something, causing the `orderedlist.getlength()` function to `return 0`, which makes none of the code in the `while()` loop execute.

**function**:

```
void rentFilm(char* filmId, char* custId, char* rentDate, char* dueDate, int numFilm)
{
    //orderedList <filmType> orderedList(numFilm);
    //filmType newItem;
    int index = 0;
    bool found = false;

    while (index < orderedList.getLength() && !found)
        {
            cout << "test" << endl;
        if (strncmp(filmId,orderedList.getAt(index).number,6) == 0 && strncmp("0000",orderedList.getAt(index).rent_id,5) == 0)//If that film is rented by NO customer
            {
                cout << "test" << endl;
                found = true;//customer can rent it
                strcpy(newItem.number,filmId);
                orderedList.retrieve(newItem);
                orderedList.remove(newItem);
                strcpy(newItem.rent_id,custId);
                strcpy(newItem.rent_date,rentDate);
                strcpy(newItem.return_date,dueDate);
                orderedList.insert(newItem);
                cout << "Rent confirmed!" << endl;
            }
        else
            {
                if (strncmp(filmId,orderedList.getAt(index).number,6) > 0 || strncmp("0000",orderedList.getAt(index).rent_id,5) > 0)
                    {
                        ++ index;
                    }
                else
                    {
                     throw string ("Not in list");
                    }
            }
        }
}
```

**Insert in orderedList class (where length is determined)**:

```
template <class elemType>
void orderedList<elemType>::insert(const elemType& newItem)
{
     int index = length - 1;
     bool found = false;

     if (length == MAX_LIST)
         throw string ("List full - no insertion");

         // index of rear is current value of length

     while (! found && index >= 0)
        if (newItem < list[index])
        {
            list[index + 1] = list [index];  // move item down
            --index;
        }
        else
            found = true;

     list [index + 1] = newItem;  // insert new item
     ++length;
}
```

**code in main where list is filled:**

```
filmFile.open("films.txt", ios::in);
filmFile >> numFilm;
filmFile.get();

orderedList <filmType> orderedList(numFilm);
filmType newItem;

readString(filmFile, newItem.number,5);
    for (int i = 0; i < numFilm; i++)
    {
         newItem.copy = filmFile.get();
     readString(filmFile, newItem.title,30);
         readString(filmFile, newItem.rent_id,4);
         readString(filmFile, newItem.rent_date,8);
         readString(filmFile, newItem.return_date,8);
         filmFile.get();

         orderedList.insert (newItem);//puts filmType struct into the ordered list.

         readString(filmFile, newItem.number,5);
    }
```

Please let me know if code from anywhere else in the program would be helpful in assessing this error.

Comment: What is `orderedlist` ? Is it a `class` ?

Comment: Yes, it is a class, and orderedList(numFilm) is a constructor

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problem with this code. You may want to give **minimal** code for `class orderlist`.

Comment: Added a bit of relevant code, does that help at all?

Comment: You are nowhere near ready to be working with templates yet.  Go back and study the difference between a class and an instance of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the line you commented out declares a variable with the same name as a class.

So when you comment it out, static functions of that class are getting invoked.

Change the declaration to something like:

```
orderedList<filmType> filmList(numFilm);
```

and then change all the references of `orderedList` in the function to `filmList`.

Comment: This has the same effect of resetting my list length to 0, just as if `orderedList` was not renamed to something else.

Comment: My guess is that you need to actually insert all the elements into the list to make its length nonzero. I don't know anything about the class you're instantiating, but I'll bet the argument you pass to the constructor just hints about how many elements to pre-allocate in a vector so it won't need to grow the vector.

Comment: Right, this is how, length is determined. As items are inserted into the class, the length increases.

Comment: There's no code to insert items into the class between when you declare it and when you use it, so it's length had better be zero. Maybe you want it to be static, or global?

Comment: I insert items in my main, if this code was in main, it'd work fine. all i'm trying to do now is break up the program into functions and the only reason I have this declaration in this function is because without it the "Missing template arguments before '.' token" error is thrown

Comment: Again, if you define the variable somewhere outside of this function, you need to pass it as a parameter or make it global. I think you need to read up on scoping and variable declaration.

Comment: Which variable? filmType or orderedList?

Comment: orderedList is a class. filmType is a variable; it's an instantiation of orderedList (which is confusingly named and would probably be better as OrderedList).

Comment: hmm, actually filmType is a type, newItem is the variable, no?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4710/discussion-between-moishe-and-mwmnj)

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that you are creating a variable with the same name as the template? When you say,

```
orderedList<filmType> orderedList(numFilm);
```

that's (sort of) like saying,

```
int int=42;
```

and then expecting `int+1` to return `43`

Try something like,

```
orderedList<filmType> ol(numFilm);
```

And changin all the other references to `orderedList`, to `ol`.

Comment: This is similar to moishes advice, it messes with the data in my program. I use `orderedList <filmType> orderedList(numFilm);` in main and it seems to work fine

Comment: Does knowing that `orderedList(numFilm);` is my orderedLists constructor have any significance here?

Comment: @mwmnj: No it isn't, it's a variable being created from that constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you populate a variable `orderedList` in `main()` and then expect it to be automatically available in `rentFilm(...)` when you declare with the same name; that is not possible. You have to pass the object to the function from `main()` or better to make that function as member method of the `class orderedList`:

```
int main ()
{
  orderedList<filmType> ol(numFilm); // variable name different (good practice)
  ... // all the populating
  orderedList.rentFilm(...);  // call the function like this
}
```

where, `rentFilem()` is now part of the `class`

```
class orderedList {
...
public:
  void rentFilm(char* filmId, char* custId, char* rentDate, char* dueDate, int numFilm);
};
```

Now inside the function, you don't have to declare variable for `orderedList`; just use `this-><method/variable>`. It should work.

Comment: You need the name of an object, not a class template, on the left side of `.`.  That's the problem the question is asking about.

Comment: @BenVoigt, that question arises if OP comments the code. In the later part of the question, OP is asking, 'why doesn't it work if the code is uncommented' ? (actually template class name and the same name of object is allowed by compiler)

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking about your "fixed" code, which has the same problem.  The comment "call the function like this" really isn't.